# AWS push notifications of configuration changes

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm creating a dashboard for our developers that helps visualise and interact with our CloudFormation stacks.

Because a CloudFormation stack can have many resources the number of calls I have to make using boto is getting quite large so the dashboard is quite slow.

I've introduced caching of boto responses but is there a better way of detecting changes than just polling the width and breadth of our infrastructure? Does AWS have some sort of change notification feed my app could subscribe to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/). I think CloudFormation talks to CloudTrail. You could probably hook up an SNS queue off of that.

Comment: This approach seems reasonable and feels like the idiomatic AWS way to be honest. Not as light or simple as I would have liked though. Marking as answered.